# Possible to disable the "6 button bug" in Leaflet without disabling keyboard controls?

Tags: leaflet

Recently, I had an issue where the button "6" on the keyboard causes the map to zoom out in Leaflet. I traced this to some known bug somehow related to French keyboards, or something like that, but didn't understand why it affects me or why it has to be "hardcoded" with no way to turn it off.

Anyway, the suggested "fix" (really a work-around) was to disable all keyboard controls in Leaflet. This fixed it, but also crippled my map system as I can no longer use the keyboard keys to navigate the map, etc.

Is there a *proper* fix for this that doesn't involve hacking the source code for Leaflet?

Comment: Mandatory "this is a feature, not a bug" link: https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/issues/5766

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could stop the propagation of the click event with a simple check to see if the number 6 has been pressed:

```
document.getElementById("mapid").onkeydown = function (e) {         
        if(e.keyCode == '54') {    // 6
             e.stopPropagation();   
        }
    };
```

Using one of the [leaflet examples](http://leafletjs.com/examples/quick-start/example-overlays.html) as a base, here's a demo with it, where `mapid` is the container holding the map:

```js
document.getElementById("mapid").onkeydown = function (e) {   
  if(e.keyCode == '54') {
    e.stopPropagation(); 
  }
 };
 

 var mymap = L.map('mapid').setView([51.505, -0.09], 13);

 L.tileLayer('https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/{id}/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoibWFwYm94IiwiYSI6ImNpejY4NXVycTA2emYycXBndHRqcmZ3N3gifQ.rJcFIG214AriISLbB6B5aw', {
  maxZoom: 18,
  attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, ' +
   '<a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, ' +
   'Imagery © <a href="http://mapbox.com">Mapbox</a>',
  id: 'mapbox.streets'
 }).addTo(mymap);
 

 L.marker([51.5, -0.09]).addTo(mymap);

 L.circle([51.508, -0.11], {
  color: 'red',
  fillColor: '#f03',
  fillOpacity: 0.5,
  radius: 500
 }).addTo(mymap);

 L.polygon([
  [51.509, -0.08],
  [51.503, -0.06],
  [51.51, -0.047]
 ]).addTo(mymap);
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.1/dist/leaflet.css" integrity="sha512-Rksm5RenBEKSKFjgI3a41vrjkw4EVPlJ3+OiI65vTjIdo9brlAacEuKOiQ5OFh7cOI1bkDwLqdLw3Zg0cRJAAQ==" crossorigin=""/>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.1/dist/leaflet.js" integrity="sha512-/Nsx9X4HebavoBvEBuyp3I7od5tA0UzAxs+j83KgC8PU0kgB4XiK4Lfe4y4cgBtaRJQEIFCW+oC506aPT2L1zw==" crossorigin=""></script>

<div id="mapid" style="width: 600px; height: 400px;"></div>
```

For comparison, here's the same snippet without:

```js
 var mymap = L.map('mapid').setView([51.505, -0.09], 13);

 L.tileLayer('https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/{id}/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoibWFwYm94IiwiYSI6ImNpejY4NXVycTA2emYycXBndHRqcmZ3N3gifQ.rJcFIG214AriISLbB6B5aw', {
  maxZoom: 18,
  attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, ' +
   '<a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, ' +
   'Imagery © <a href="http://mapbox.com">Mapbox</a>',
  id: 'mapbox.streets'
 }).addTo(mymap);
 

 L.marker([51.5, -0.09]).addTo(mymap);

 L.circle([51.508, -0.11], {
  color: 'red',
  fillColor: '#f03',
  fillOpacity: 0.5,
  radius: 500
 }).addTo(mymap);

 L.polygon([
  [51.509, -0.08],
  [51.503, -0.06],
  [51.51, -0.047]
 ]).addTo(mymap);
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.1/dist/leaflet.css" integrity="sha512-Rksm5RenBEKSKFjgI3a41vrjkw4EVPlJ3+OiI65vTjIdo9brlAacEuKOiQ5OFh7cOI1bkDwLqdLw3Zg0cRJAAQ==" crossorigin=""/>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.1/dist/leaflet.js" integrity="sha512-/Nsx9X4HebavoBvEBuyp3I7od5tA0UzAxs+j83KgC8PU0kgB4XiK4Lfe4y4cgBtaRJQEIFCW+oC506aPT2L1zw==" crossorigin=""></script>

<div id="mapid" style="width: 600px; height: 400px;"></div>
```

Comment: Yes! That works! Nice. However, one might argue that this kind of thing should never be necessary, and the library itself should not only tell you about it but provide a nice option for French users to enable this weird behaviour and default to not doing it.